# PHP How to log to "FireFox Quantum" Developer Web Console from php script

Tags: php, logging, firebug, firefox-quantum

I use FireBug before FireFox updated to Quantum.

I use `FB::info` and `FB::log` from `FirePHP` but now it not working.

Now i again need such debugging tool.

Is there a way to log from php script to FireFox Quantum Web Developer Console